Memory usage unstoppably increasing when updating SwiftData Object from Timer
For a kind of podcast player I need to periodically update a swiftData object to keep track of the listening progress. (Happy to hear if there are better ways) I need to do this in many places in my app so I wanted to extract the modelContext into a Singleton so I can write a global function that starts the timer. In doing so I stumbled upon a problem: The memory used by my app is steadily increasing and the device is turning hot.
@Observable
class Helper {
    static let shared = Helper()
    var modelContext: ModelContext?
}

@main
struct SingletontestApp: App {
    let modelContainer: ModelContainer
    init() {
        do {
            modelContainer = try ModelContainer(
                for: Item.self, Item.self
            )
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not initialize ModelContainer")
        }
        Helper.shared.modelContext = modelContainer.mainContext
    }
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(modelContainer)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Query private var items: [Item]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    Text(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: updateItemPeriodically) {
                        Label("Change random", systemImage: "dice")
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(timestamp: Date())
            Helper.shared.modelContext!.insert(newItem)
        }
    }

    @MainActor
    func updateItemPeriodically() { // Doesn't matter if run as global or local func
        let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Item>(sortBy: [SortDescriptor(\.timestamp)])
        let results = (try? Helper.shared.modelContext?.fetch(descriptor)) ?? []
        var element = results.randomElement()

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { timer in // Smaller time intervals worsen the problem
            Helper.shared.modelContext?.delete(element)
            element.timestamp = Date.now
            Helper.shared.modelContext?.insert(element)

        }

    }
}


Calling save() manually or automatically in the timer does not have any effect. I am not sure about my general way of keeping track of listening process so if you think there is a better way, feel free to correct me.
Thanks for your help
EDIT:
I was able to pin the problem down to this function. Timers don't have an effect but make the problem more obvious by running the function more often.
func doManually() {
    let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Item>()
    let results = (try? Helper.shared.modelContext?.fetch(FetchDescriptor<Item>())) ?? []
    let element = results.first!
    element.timestamp = Date.now
    Helper.shared.modelContext?.insert(element) // This updates the element without inserting a new one
}

In this case .insert updates the object. This is exactly what I am looking for except the increasing memory.

Every time you call updateItemPeriodically you are creating a new timer, so you will have multiple timers running, each of which are fetching all the data and sorting it. Is that what you want?  Wouldn't it be better to have a single timer that does whatever needs doing when it fires? Use the profiler and memory Instruments tools to analyse your app

Have a try to remove timer, just simply do element?.timestamp = Date.now it is fine for your intention to random an element.

The timer seems not to be the problem. The memory usage also increases when doing that manually. The timer just makes it more obvious.

What’s up with the delete/insert you added in the last edit?

results is only a copy. Changing it has no effect to the actual database. Therefore I need to perform delete and insert to change the database and not just the copy of it. So the code before was duplicating the database all the time so I fixed that but the memory usage is still increasing, just slower.

Changing it has no effect to the actual database, this must mean that you have some other issue with your code because that statement doesn’t make sense. There was no duplication of the database in your earlier code unless you are talking about your real code and not the example in your question.

I am not sure how to phrase it properly. Modifying results dose not change the persistent data. It seems to be somewhat of a copy of the swiftdata objects that match the fetchDescriptor. (in this case all) So every time the func is run, the items get loaded into that var and possibly not deleted afterwards.

They exists in memory for the duration of the scope they were created in so in this case until the function exits. The data of course exists in the SwiftData persistent store as well but nothing is duplicated in the sense that you get more data.

And don’t need to do an insert to update an existing object in SwiftData, just update a property and call save() on the model context. Honestly I think this is more about you not understanding how classes and a persistence framework as SwiftData works than it’s a memory issue.

You mean just call save() instead of insert()? This doesn't change anything. I know it would be like that if I'd be using @Querybut I can't use that.

May i ask if we have a solution for this? The consumed memory keeps going up and not even go down after navigating to another screen, I think there is something that duplicate data instead of just updating it
Cars[index].price = newPrice


It looks like this is not an answer to the question but rather a side question.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
